# Unable to set finite retention period for Temporal tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Azure DevOps Classic Release pipelines to deploy an on-premise SQL database (DACPAC file, Target Platform 2019) using the "SQL Server Database deploy" task.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group-v0?view=azure-pipelines

My Visual Studio DB project has some System Versioned temporal tables with their corresponding History tables. I have finite retention periods set on them using the below SQL syntax

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee (
    <<Column definitions>>
    )
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EmployeeHistory, HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD = 6 MONTHS, DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON));
```

Although my tables are deployed correctly, the retention period is not being set on them. They are always deployed with an infinite retention period and the 6 months that I provided on the table definition doesn't apply. If I run this script manually using SSMS, then the retention period is set correctly, the issue is happening only with Azure DevOps deployments.

Note that the flag `is_temporal_history_retention_enabled=1` in `sys.databases`